# Is there an automatic way to create a discriminated union for all interfaces in a namespace?

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript (2.5 at the moment, but I can update to 2.6 if needed).

I have a namespace with some interfaces:

```
export namespace Interfaces {
    export interface One {
        kind: "One"
    }

    export interface Two {
        kind: "Two"
    }

    export interface Three {
        kind: "Three"
    }
}
```

I then create a discriminated union for those interfaces:

```
export type KnownInterfaces = Interfaces.One | Interfaces.Two | Interfaces.Three;
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically so that I don't have to manually update the discriminated union every time I add an interface?

Something like:

```
export type KnownInterfaces = discriminatedUnion(Interfaces);
```

Comment: Nope don't think so, there is no way to iterate the interfaces in the namespace

Comment: You could automate it with a script using the TS compiler API.

Answer (score 4):

A different angle of approach here might be to keep a type that's a mapping instead of a namespace:

```
export type Interfaces = {
  One: { kind: 'One' },
  Two: { kind: 'Two' },
  Three: { kind: 'Three' }
}
export type KnownInterfaces = Interfaces[keyof Interfaces]
```

You can add as many properties to `Interfaces` as you want, and `KnownInterfaces` will remain the union of them.

One wrinkle here is that you can't use dot notation to refer to the individual interfaces: `Interfaces.One` will fail to compile. You *can* use [indexed-access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) notation (also called "lookup types") to do it, so `Interfaces['One']` will work.  I can imagine that getting annoying, so you can always give them dot-notation names:

```
export namespace Interfaces {
  export type One = Interfaces['One']
  export type Two = Interfaces['Two']
  export type Three = Interfaces['Three']
}
```

But now you're back in the realm of doing something in multiple places when you add an interface, so your mileage may vary.  Maybe only name the ones you need easy names for?

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!